# My texture doesn't apply on a surface but does on an other

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

My problem is a bit curious ! I've got 2 simple planes. And on them I apply a texture, exactly the same. But on one of them, the texture is not showing. Can you explain me why ?

One precision : the surface in which the texture is not apply is an import of Sketchup, but I flattened it to have a very simple plane, I recalculate normal, I verified there is no double faces... so I don't understand why I have this problem.
Thx for your help !

[image: 2 planes]

Comment: Check the UVs of the plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @lemon ! You're right, there is no UV map for the bad plane. Question solved. Thanks again for you very fast help !!

Comment: To elaborate ... Blender gives a Plane primitive a default UV map.. Sketchup does not.